# When setting automatic height to container, it shifts the page over

Tags: html, css

So pretty much, I have a container with two divs inside. I have each div set to float to different sides. One to the left and one to the right, now the issue I'm having is that since I have to set the height manually, it shifts the page like 10 pixels over from the original spot. So when I load a different page, it isn't lined up vertically. Here's the .gif of it and here's my code. This website is for my webdesign class. Thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7T53.jpg

index.html (page that's shifted over)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/stylesheet.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="banner">
                <img src="images/banner.png">
            </div>
            <div class="navbar">
                <a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
                <a href="news.html">News</a>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">Parts 
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="cases.html">Cases</a>
                        <a href="motherboards.html">Motherboards</a>
                        <a href="processors.html">Processors</a>
                        <a href="graphics.html">Graphics Cards</a>
                        <a href="storage.html">Storage</a>
                        <a href="powersupplies.html">Power Supplies</a>
                        <a href="ram.html">RAM</a>
                        <a href="other.html">Other</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">Builds 
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#">Placeholder</a>
                        <a href="#">Placeholder</a>
                        <a href="#">Placeholder</a>
                        <a href="#">Placeholder</a>
                        <a href="#">Placeholder</a>
                        <a href="#">Placeholder</a>
                        <a href="#">Placeholder</a>
                        <a href="#">Placeholder</a>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="contact" id="navright">
                    <a href="contact.html" style="float:right;">Contact</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="featured">
                <div id="product_left">
                    <img src="images/featured.gif" id="featured_gif">
                </div>
                <div id="product_right">
                    awdaw
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="welcome">
                <h1 class="welcome_header">Welcome</h1>
                <p class="welcome_text">Here at Terry's Computers we are determined to make our customers experience as 
                    stress free as possible.  We will help every customer find the best deal possible
                    for their budget.  Here we have computer parts such as motherboards, processors, and
                    more to offer.  We also offer prebuilt computers that range from productivity, gaming,
                    or whatever the customer desires.  We also take custom requests that can more suit our customers.  
                    We can help you find the perfect computer that will satisfy your needs.  If you have any
                    questions or suggestions head over to the <a href="contact.html">Contact</a> page and send us an email.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                <p class="footer_text">Yeet</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

stylesheet.css

```
/*
Color Scheme
http://paletton.com/#uid=14x0u0k++k3ZJvC+Wpu+Zer+W78
*/
body{
    background-color: #25004E;
    margin: 0;
}
.container{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 15px auto;
}
.banner{
    margin-top: 15px;
}
/* Navigation Menu */
.navbar {
    margin-top: 15px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
}
.navbar a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}
.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #23004E;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #333;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #23004E;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
.active{
    background-color: #400089;
}
.featured{
    margin-top: 15px;
    background-color: #420089;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 30px;
    overflow: auto;
}
#product_left{
    float: left;
    width: 432px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 13px;

}
#product_right{
    float: right;
    width: 432px;
    background-color: #5201AA;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.welcome{
    margin-top: 15px;
    background-color: #420089;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 30px;
}
.welcome_header{
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size: 25pt;
    text-align: center;
}
.welcome_text{
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    width: 800px;
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 30px auto;
    text-indent: 50px;
    font-size: 13pt;
}
.footer{
    margin-top: 15px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #333;
}
.footer_text{
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
```

and finally, my news.html (page that's in the original position)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/stylesheet.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="banner">
                <img src="images/banner.png">
            </div>
            <div class="navbar">
                <a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
                <a href="news.html">News</a>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">Parts 
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="cases.html">Cases</a>
                        <a href="motherboards.html">Motherboards</a>
                        <a href="processors.html">Processors</a>
                        <a href="graphics.html">Graphics Cards</a>
                        <a href="storage.html">Storage</a>
                        <a href="powersupplies.html">Power Supplies</a>
                        <a href="ram.html">RAM</a>
                        <a href="other.html">Other</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">Builds 
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#">Placeholder</a>
                        <a href="#">Placeholder</a>
                        <a href="#">Placeholder</a>
                        <a href="#">Placeholder</a>
                        <a href="#">Placeholder</a>
                        <a href="#">Placeholder</a>
                        <a href="#">Placeholder</a>
                        <a href="#">Placeholder</a>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="contact" id="navright">
                    <a href="contact.html" style="float:right;">Contact</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                <p class="footer_text">Yeet</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what browser do you use?

Comment: I use chrome. What does that have to do with it?

Comment: You've posted way too much code here. What container are you talking about? You have classes on your divs, so you should probably tell us what specific div you're talking about. Try and limit the code to just the problem area. If you aren't seeing the issue, you know to broaden the scope. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: is the height or the width that shifts over ?

Comment: @terryjtowell Your question was pretty clear, i answered it. You should put it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

It is a normal behavior and a famous question. It is because the content of one of your page is bigger than the screen and the other content page is not bigger than the screen. It cause the scrollbar on the right side to appears and disappear depending of the page.

You can fix it like that :

```css
/* One of these two solutions at the beginning of your css file */

html { overflow-y: scroll; } /* Will display the bar all the time */

/* OR */

html { margin-left: calc(100vw - 100%); }
```

See : https://css-tricks.com/elegant-fix-jumping-scrollbar-issue/

Answer (score 0):

> It is caused because of the scrollbar appearing on the index page and
>   not appear on the news page.

When you give a static height you intentionally cause a scrollbar to appear and width of the page appear to be same then. **Everything is normal in this case.**

> If you really obsessed to make them identical, either insert enough
>   content to news page to make a scroll appear or calculate the widths
>   more precisely(use % instead of px, em, rem).